# CastVideos-ios demo fails to connect (GCKError Code=20 "Application was not found")

Tags: swift, google-cast

I'm trying to get ChromeCast working in my swift app using google-cast-sdk. When I found it was not working, I tried the demo app (CastVideos-ios) and got the exact same results (ie. does not connect).

I changed the bundle identifier of the CastVideos-Swift app to my bundle ID so I could run it on my device. I double-checked my App ID in the iOS Dev portal has the WiFi capability enabled, and of course it is enabled in the Xcode project file in both the CastVideos-swift demo, and in my own app.

Additionally, I have verified many times that my iPhone is on the same WiFI network as the ChromeCast device connected to my TV. I have tested the ChromeCast device using the YouTube App - works perfectly. When I tap the ChromeCast button in the YouTube app, it just throws to my "Living Room TV" - doesn't even ask me, I guess because there is only 1 CC device.

When I run the CastVideos-swift demo app (or my app) and I tap the ChromeCast button, I get a popup asking me to choose, and there is ONLY one option "Nearby Device" - from what I read, this seems to indicate that there is already a problem, that the app is treating my CC device like a "Guest" as if it were on a different WiFi, but its not (and again, YouTube app works) - so, I tap Nearby Devices and the Connect fails so I put in the code. Nothing happens in the app or TV, the debugger shows this error:

*[GCKCastDeviceController notifyDidFailToConnectToApplicationWithError:], message: Failed to connect to app with error: Error Domain=com.google.cast.GCKError Code=20 "Application was not found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Application was not found}*

Additionally, it may be important (or not) but I am seeing this message in the logger also, before the failed to connect.

*[GCKNNetworkUtils getTwoLowerBytesFromNetworkAddress:], message: Invalid network address*

Finally, I find it fascinating that when I connect with YouTube app and cast a video - and then switch to the CastVideos-Swift demo, when I tap the CC button, instead of saying "Nearby devices" it correctly says "Living Room TV" and below that in parenthesis it says "Youtube" - which appears to indicate that it is aware that the YouTube app is currently casting to this device) - and YET, when I tap the Living Room TV device, I get the exact same error (the YouTube streaming continues to play without interruption).

My best idea is that it has something to do with my App ID since i used the same bundle ID for the demo app as my own app. But, except for turning on the WiFi capability, I cant think of anything else which would make it fail that I have read so far.

Note that I read that the YouTube app is not a good test of discoverability (it has access to internal APIs?) - I tried another app which was ChromeCast enabled, and it worked perfectly, no guest mode login, just asked me to pick "Living Room TV" and it worked fine.

Maybe someone here has seen this before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be a bug you may want to report it in their [GitHub](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios/issues/new) or the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc).

Comment: I think you should disable guest mode [link](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/guest_mode) and try again. If it was not working, you should feedback me, and we try to find another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it turned out to be a bogus google cast app ID I was given by the project owner.

Comment: Hi , i want to show/mirroring only the app screen, is it possible without playing any media ? Please provide some code example if possible. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain this even further? It is lacking of information